# Replace/Remove first instance of a string within a string case-insensitive and maintain the existing string

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to replace or remove **only** the first instance of a string within a string.

For example, if I'm given the string "Say hello say Goodbye" I want to be able to replace the first instance of "say" regardless of its case, but while maintaining the rest of the string.

I've tried (where `message` is the provided string):

```
messageWithoutTrigger = message.toLowerCase().replace(t.toLowerCase(), "").replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```

and this worked but didn't preserve the existing string's case of course. Then I tried:

```
messageWithoutTrigger = messageWithoutTrigger.replace(new RegExp(t.toLowerCase(), "ig"),"")
                                                     .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
```

which preserves the existing string's case, but removes all instances instead of just the first.

How can I just remove the first instance of a provided string from another string, while preserving the case of the string that remains?

Comment: `g` on a regex means **global**.  Take it off to only match once

Comment: and use `i` to make it case insensitive `'SaY hello say Goodbye'.replace(/say/i, 'replacement');`

Comment: `new RegExp(t.toLowerCase(), "ig")` <= yeah, this is weird.  It is matching globally and insensitively against a letter, that you are lowercasing.  Rather than `new RegExp(t.toUpperCase())` to only match the first uppercase one

Answer (score 0):

```js
var original = 'sally Say hello Say Goodbye George';

function removeFirstUpperCase ( character ) {
  return original.replace( new RegExp( character.toUpperCase() ), character.toLowerCase() );
}

console.log( removeFirstUpperCase( 's' ) );
console.log( removeFirstUpperCase( 'S' ) );

console.log( removeFirstUpperCase( 'g' ) );
console.log( removeFirstUpperCase( 'G' ) );
```

If you want to replace the first uppercased character with a lowercased version, then your regular expression should just match against that one character rather than trying to be insensitive or match globally.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```js
var mainTest = "Blah Say hello say Goodbye";
var message = "say"
var indx = mainTest.toLowerCase().indexOf(message.toLowerCase())
console.log(mainTest.substr(0,indx)+mainTest.substr(indx+message.length))
```